# Brezis' exercise 4.22.4: convergence in weak topology $\sigma(L^1, L^\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $f, f_n \in L^1 (\Omega)$ be non-negative for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Assume that $\int_\Omega f_n \to \int_\Omega f$ and $\int_E f_n \to \int_E f$ for every $E \in \mathcal F$ with $\mu(E) < \infty$. Then $f_n \to f$ in the weak topology $\sigma(L^1, L^\infty)$.

Could you confirm if my attempt is fine?

---

**Proof** Fix $B \in \mathcal F$ where $\mu(B)$ is not necessarily finite. It suffices to prove that $\int_B f_n \to \int_B f$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$.

Because $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, there is an increasing sequence $(\Omega_m) \subset \mathcal F$ such that $\Omega_m \uparrow \Omega$ and that $\mu(\Omega_m) < \infty$ for all $m$. Let $B_m := \Omega_m \cap B$. Let $C := \Omega \setminus B$ and $C_m := \Omega_m \cap C$. Then $B_m \uparrow B$ and $C_m \uparrow C$. By dominated convergence theorem, there is $M \in \mathbb N$ such that $\|1_{B_m} f - 1_B f\|_1 < \varepsilon$ and $\|1_{C_m} f - 1_C f\|_1 < \varepsilon$ for all $m \ge \overline m$. Let $B'_m := B \setminus B_m$ and $C'_m := C \setminus C_m$. Then $\|1_{B'_m} f\|_1 < \varepsilon$ and $\|1_{C'_m} f\|_1 < \varepsilon$ for all $m \ge \overline m$.

Clearly, $\mu(B_{\overline m})+\mu(C_{\overline m}) < \infty$, so
$$
\lim_n \int_{B_{\overline m}} f_n = \int_{B_{\overline m}} f
\quad \text{and} \quad
\lim_n \int_{C_{\overline m}} f_n = \int_{C_{\overline m}} f.
$$

Let $D_{\overline m} := B'_{\overline m} \cup C'_{\overline m}$. Notice that $D_{\overline m} = \Omega \setminus (B_{\overline m} \cup C_{\overline m})$, so
$$
 \lim_n \int_{D_{\overline m}} f_n = \int_{D_{\overline m}} f .
$$

Because $f, f_n$ are non-negative, we get $\lim_n \|1_{D_{\overline m}} f_n \|_1= \|1_{D_{\overline m}} f \|_1$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\bigg | \int_{B'_{\overline m}} f_n - \int_{B'_{\overline m}} f \bigg |  &\le \bigg | \int_{B'_{\overline m}} f_n \bigg | + \bigg |\int_{B'_{\overline m}} f \bigg | \\
&\le \bigg | \int_{D_{\overline m}} f_n \bigg | + \bigg |\int_{D_{\overline m}} f \bigg | \\
&= \|1_{D_{\overline m}} f_n \|_1 + \|1_{D_{\overline m}} f \|_1.
\end{align}
$$

Finally,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_n \bigg | \int_B f_n - \int_B f \bigg |  &\le \lim_n \bigg | \int_{B_{\overline m}} f_n - \int_{B_{\overline m}} f \bigg |  + \lim_n \bigg | \int_{B'_{\overline m}} f_n - \int_{B'_{\overline m}} f \bigg | \\
&\le \lim_n \|1_{D_{\overline m}} f_n \|_1 + \|1_{D_{\overline m}} f \|_1 \\
&= 2 \|1_{D_{\overline m}} f \|_1 \\
&= 2 \|1_{B'_m} f\|_1 + 2 \|1_{C'_m} f\|_1 \\
&\le 4 \varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$

The claim then follows by taking the limit $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I could not see how the hypothesis $\int_\Omega f_n \to \int_\Omega f$ is used in your approach. If you don't mind, please post your proof as an answer.

Comment: Sorry for my hurried comment earlier. /I see now that the problems not as straight forward as I thought earlier. In any case, I think there is a typo in your posting: $D_m=B^c_m\cup C^c_m\neq (\Omega\setminus(B_m\cup C_m)$. In fact $D_m=B^c_m\cup C^c_m=(\Omega\setminus(B_m\cap C_m)$

Comment: @OliverDíaz $B \cap C = \emptyset$, so $B_m\cap C_m = \emptyset$...

Comment: (+1) your idea is fine, I think that there are a few computations that you can do without as they make things a little confusing. You'll get better as you write your own answers, which is commendable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things can be stremlined:

Suppose $\Omega_n\nearrow\Omega$, $C=\Omega\setminus B$. Then
$\Omega_n\cap B=B_n\nearrow B$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Notice that
$B\setminus B_n=B\setminus \Omega_n=B\cap(\Omega\setminus\Omega_n)$

Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $N$ such that $\int_{\Omega\setminus\Omega_N}|f|<\varepsilon$.

\begin{align}
(f-f_n,\mathbb{1}_B)&=(f-f_n,\mathbb{1}_{B_N})+(f-f_n,\mathbb{1}_{B\setminus B_N})\\
&=(f-f_n,\mathbb{1}_{B_N}) + (f,\mathbb{1}_{B\setminus B_N})-(f_n\mathbb{1}_{B\setminus B_N})
\end{align}

Since $f,f_n$ are nonnegative

- $(f,\mathbb{1}_{B\setminus B_N})=\int_{B\setminus B_N}f\leq\int_{\Omega\setminus\Omega_N}f<\varepsilon$.
- Similarly, $(f_n,\mathbb{1}_{B\setminus B_N})\leq (f_n,\mathbb{1}_{\Omega\setminus \Omega_N})\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}(f,\mathbb{1}_{\Omega\setminus \Omega_N})<\varepsilon$
  Putting things together
  $$\limsup_n|(f-f_n,\mathbb{1}_B)|\leq2\varepsilon
  $$

Comment: This is indeed much simpler and clearer than mine. Thank you so much for your approach!